# spring @transactional does not work with multitenancy

Tags: spring, hibernate, multi-tenant

I am developing multi-tenancy application using spring 4/hibernate 4 (no jpa). My user data for all tenants is on master database. Rest all tables are on individual tenant database. Using Spring security to authenticate the user. If user gets authenticated then I set tenatIdentifier.

For User Management each tenant admin needs to get connected to master database irrespective of their own tenantIdentifier. I am doing some thing like below.

```
    My service method 
     @Transactional
     public void saveUser() {
         dao.saveUser();
     }

    My Dao method
    public void saveUser() {

    Session session = sessionFactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier("master").openSession();
        //Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        //some dummy code to show case my problem
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setUserName("manisha");
        user1.setPassword("password");
        user1.setFirstName("manisha first");
        user1.setLastName("manisha last");
        user1.setEmail("manisha@email.com");
        user1.setState("Active");
        user1.setTenantName("manisha");
        session.persist(user1);
        //transaction.commit();
        session.close();

}
```

The problem is my user does not get persist unless I uncomment "transaction" code. So it seems in my case spring @Transactional does not work.

On the other hand for all other tables which resides on tenant db and if I get session using sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(), then data persists well inside tenant database. If any error occurs, it gets rolled back properly. So spring @Transactional annotation seems to be working as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?. Any help is most welcome

Comment: Do you have multiple dataSources/sessionFactories - and one transactionmanager per dataSource/sessionFactory?

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work, you are opening sessions yourself, how should Spring manage the session that you start yourself. So it basically works as expected. Spring tx management will only work with `getCurrentSession` as soon as you start using `openSession` you are on your own and need to manage the session yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was very helpful.